# Discover Git object hash based on path and branch

Tags: git

I'm writing a small web Git visualization tool and i wanted to convert a file path and a branch:

```
master repository/folder/test => a39bc19d82890f25df2d08d8bea627bb4354e8d8
mybranch repository/folder/test/myfile.py => 76e2242459d360f7429ed748426e660b6dacc9a9
```

Into a Git object hash, so i can properly use `git show` and `git cat-file`, as well `git ls-tree`. My app currently looks like this:

```
show.php?h=76e2242459d360f7429ed748426e660b6dacc9a9
```

I want to convert paths into something more usable, like:

```
show.php?branch=master&path=repository/folder/test/myfile.py
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use the `branch:path` notation instead of the hash. All the commands you mention work on that. Will the be sufficient or do you still need the hash?

Comment: That's great, didn't know about this alternative notation. Now, does it work with tags too?

Comment: Any [treeish](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch:path notation was the solution. Thanks Noufal Ibrahim!